# How to add tags to logretention custom function using AWS CDK

Tags: aws-cdk

I am using AWS CDK Typescript to generate my lambda function

```
import { Function as lambdaFunction } from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda'

const my_lambda = new lambdaFunction(this, 'my Lambda', {
            code: Code.fromBucket(
                lambdaBucket,
                'python36/helloworld/hello-world-python3.zip'
            ),
            runtime: Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
            handler: 'lambda_function.lambda_handler',
            functionName: 'MyLambda',
            logRetention: RetentionDays.ONE_MONTH,
        })
```

This works fine, but behind the scenes, CDK is creating another lambda responsible for adding the logs.

It is easy to add tags to the lambda function I created using `Tags.of(my_lambda).add('Name','tag name')`
I would like to add tags to the underlying lambda function. Does anyone know a way of tagging the underlying function?

Answer (score 0):

Move tagging code to stack level, this will apply tags to all resources created within the stack

```
import aws_cdk.core as _core

tags = _core.Tags.of(<<Your Stack Name>>)
tags.add("environment", env_name)
```

This will tags to all resources created within your stack

Comment: Thx - I know, 
I am giving general tags on a stack level, but for budget reporting, we need to individually tag the different constructs. For instance, a lambda got a tag called 'name' with value 'lambda1' while a bucket in the stack has a tag 'name' with a value of 'bucket1'
I just want to be able to tag the custom lambda that is generated when creating the LogRetention

Comment: This actually does not work. I have the same use case but provide my tags on the whole Stack, and nothing gets propagated to the LogRetention lambda function.
I guess it's because it's dynamically generated, but it looks like a CFN / CDK bug to me.